# Scala Slick: how to serialize the result of a query to a variable table

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework, slick

I would like to provide a select method to a controller that takes a table name as parameter and returns the result of the SELECT query as JSON. So far I have done this:

```
def specialSelect(tableName: String) = Action.async {
  val tq: TableQuery[_] = tableObjectFactory(tableName)
  val res: Future[Seq[_]] = db.run(tq.result)
  res.map { p:Seq[_] => Ok(p.toJson) }
}
```

where `tableObjectFactory` takes my table name and returns a `TableQuery` of the specific type:

```
def tableObjectFactory(tableName: String): TableQuery[_] = {
  tableName match {
    case "users" => TableQuery[Users]
    case "projects" => TableQuery[Projects]
  }
}
```

If fails because there is no JSON serializer defined for a a generic `Seq[_]` (actually `_` should be a `Product with Serializable`, not sure if that helps).

The table name is not known in advance (found in the URL, such as in `"/special_select/<tableName>"`), and I have 120 such tables so I can't just implement it for each table.

Is there a way to serialize *any* `Seq[_]`, knowing that the `_` is always a Slick row result (e.g. a case class `UsersRow`), whatever the table is?

I have read about Generic DAOs and ActiveSlick, but I am not sure if should go so far.

Comment: Each case class will have different number and type of fields, So it would be difficult write general Json writes. Try providing `implicit json format` for each of the model. `Json.format[User]` inside the companion object.

Comment: Scala doesn't care what Json formatter I provide for each of the row objects, because it only sees `Seq[(Product with Serializable)]`, or something similar. It cannot know that the case classes I provided a Json formatter for are the only ones it will ever see.

Comment: thats right but the number of tuples in Product varies based on the object you pass. So there cannot be one format which can explain how to convert the Product into JSON. You have to use from solution using Reflection. try using Gson library

Comment: Gson almost works. It returns something super weird but that at least contains the expected result!
On the other hand, I found a function capable of turning any case class (Product) into a Json, so I have hope, but Slick says that a row has type `found : ((_$1$u#TableElementType) forSome ...)` but my function `required: Product`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson worked, thanks @pamu. Add

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.0"
```

to build.sbt, then this will convert any `Seq[_]` or rows to a JsArray that can be given as http response:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import play.api.libs.json._

val gson: Gson = new Gson()

def slickToJson(res: Seq[_]): JsArray = {
  JsArray(res.map(gson.toJson).map(Json.parse))
}

// in controller Action.async:
db.run(...).map(p => Ok(slickToJson(p)))
```

Rows are serialized to String by Gson, then parsed back to JsObjects by Play api, then put in a JsArray. I couldn't find better.